# Alt key in Autodesk Maya 2011 using Gnome

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

This might be a dumb question, but I've googgled and searched for it and couldn't find any good answer.

I am using Maya 2011, which usually uses the ALT key as a shortcut by default for a lot of things (select objects, etc...). However, since Gnome uses ALT + click to drag windows, Maya does not let me use ALT for anything, and apparently the Windows key has taken now this role, so I can select objects through Windows key + click while ALT + click drags the whole window.

I know I can change the ALT key behaviour in Gnome in Windows Preferences -> Movement Key, but this does only changes ALT behaviour in Gnome, while Maya still uses Windows key for selection.

I am asking this because in KDE was a very simple thing to change, I remember I just changed something about modifier key, and it all went back to normal, without changing any configuration inside Maya, and I believe Gnome has to have a similar option that I cannot find.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'm such an idiot :)

All I had to do was restart Maya after setting Preferences -> Windows -> Movement Key and set it to Super. Now you drag your windows using Super + click, and in Maya your ALT key behaves as expected.

I was about to delete this question, but I will leave it in the system, just in case someone falls into the same error......

Cheers!

Comment: Dan - well done - please add your comment as an answer.  You will be able to accept it in a few hours time.

Comment: @fossfreedom If I do so I get this message "Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

I will add the answer in a few hours then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm such an idiot :)

All I had to do was restart Maya after setting Preferences -> Windows -> Movement Key and set it to Super. Now you drag your windows using Super + click, and in Maya your ALT key behaves as expected.

I was about to delete this question, but I will leave it in the system, just in case someone into the same error...... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Go to

```
System->Preferences->Keyboard
Layouts
> Options...
   > Alt/Win key behavior
        > Left Alt is swapped with Left Win
```

Now you can run Maya.

[http://rodmena.ourway.ir](http://ourway.ir/pages/blog?u=rodmena&bpid=6d5f6a70-9f83-47ac-be7c-267672333191)